# The idiom "be first in Maths"

Tags: idioms

I came across the idiom "be first in Maths". But I couldn't find any with other school subjects. 
Is it possible to say "be first in Geography/Physics"? Or the preposition "in" goes only whith Maths?
When did this idiom "be first in Maths" come to be?

Comment: Using "be best **in** something" sounds more natural to native speakers.

Comment: "Maths" is British English. In American English it's singular, "Math".

Comment: It should work the same way with any school subject. Where did you come across this phrase to begin with?

Comment: @TRomano Use of the word "first" in this context also strikes me as British English.

Comment: @Keiki , my child's teacher told he should use "in". (we study  British English)

Comment: @ Keiki , the reason I began looking for any other cases of using 'be first in' is that I always thought that I should say 'first at" as "be good/bad AT Maths, Geography" and told my kid so, but the teacher didn't agree

Comment: @Andorian Okay, now I understand. Yes, you can be "Good at geography", "Best in geography", or "First in geography". You could use all of those for maths or any other subject. If someone were running a race, and won, you could say, "They came in first".

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that it is equivalent to:

> Be (ranked) first in math

And so it is possible to be first in other subjects, so long as there is some way to rank participants.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, "Maths" is referring to the group (i.e. Maths class), not the subject of the lesson.

- You can be first **in** the group - first in Maths.
- You can be the best **at** the subject - best at Maths.
- You can also be the best **in** the group - best in Maths.
- But you **can't** be the first **at** the subject - first at Maths. X

The same rules apply for other classes/subjects.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you were right, but after that I realised that it was *"first"*, not *"good"*.

We do not say *"be first in/at"* but we say *"be first for"*.

Definition of "for" by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/for)

> `with the object or purpose of`
>   
>   
> ***e.g.*** to run for exercise.

**be first** *[with what? Math.]* **for Math**

Nevertheless, it is still possible to use *in/at* for similar cases.

> *be good at Math*

your Math is good

> *be good in Math*

you are good in Math **(class/lesson)**

Comment: As a Canadian born in Britain, *for* in this context sounds very foreign to me. *At* or *in* seem much more natural.